# heroku add new derectry without replaicing exiting files

Tags: git, heroku

i want to host php files on heroku .and i'm very new..i did it by following commands .my local directory is "people_info"

1) git clone git@heroku.com:people-info.git -o heroku

2) cd people-info

3) git add -A

4) git commit -am "Added one file"

5) git push heroku master

i can add files without replacing entire .but now i have created a directory named "infox"
and 2 php files and 1 imag file is in it..i want to add this local folder to heroku ..
i want cammand for that
 .i want help.thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very similar to what you've done before:

1. git add -A (at the infox level)
2. git commit -m "Added directory"
3. git push heroku master

With these steps, you add *infox* to version control, commit it to your local branch, and push your local branch to the `heroku` remote.

Comment: at the infox level what did you mean by it ?cd infox ??is it

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Also, if the answer helped you, please provide an upvote and/or an accept.

Comment: yes but i didn't test it .that's why i didn't response .i will check it today as soon as .then i will vote you up

Comment: it will too much help for me